# Search places in Google Maps

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift

How can I plot markers on Google Maps of all the nearby McDonald's branch (for example) wherein the user won't need to type "McDonald's", the app will automatically plot all the branches near him

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a marker

To add a marker you create a GMSMarker object that includes a position, title and set its map.

The below example demonstrates how to add a marker to an existing GMSMapView object. The marker is created at coordinates 10,10, and displays the string "Hello world" in an info window when clicked.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(10, 10);
GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
marker.title = @"Hello World";
marker.map = mapView_;
```

you need to give coordinated to make markers or else you need find all McDonald's coordinates and use that to plot markers

http://www.distancesfrom.com/Mcdonalds-latitude-latitude-Mcdonalds-latitude-Mcdonalds-longitude/LatLongHistory/368517.aspx

Use the above link to find Mcdonalds latitude and latitude values

Comment: Thanks. But how do i get the coordinates?

Comment: I would like it to display the nearby only, i know how to make markers already, what i don't know is how to get the nearby mcdonald's coordinates.

Comment: That you will get from the link which i have given

Comment: I don't know whether any APi's are there for finding Mcdonalds lat,long values, Try to find it

Comment: You mean i have to get all the coordinates? I think that's not efficient

Comment: btw, McDonald's is just an example. I just need to find the the locations near the user, not all the branches.

Comment: search any API are present